# avoid loading large number of objects in heap for route calculation in map

Tags: java, memory, dictionary, navigation

I've given java program which calculates turn by turn navigation data(route direction). The code starts by loading map information(lat-longs,paths etc) from flat files(generated from database) which amounts to 6 GB. Once all the information is loaded, route is calculated using the loaded data and in turn providing the turn-by-turn navigation.
Is there a better design for such applications which involve calculations using large number of objects to lessen overall memory consumption?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you're using the loaded data. I think you may be able to use `java.io.RandomAccessFile` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html. It allows you to read through/modify files, without loading them into memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can index the map information in a graph database, e.g. [Neo4J](http://www.neo4j.org/) - this should make it easier to only load the relevant part of the map needed for the route calculation, rather than having to load the entire map into memory.

You can use a more traditional relational database instead of a graph database, but you'll probably need to come up with a reasonable schema for your data rather than relying on the database to take care of indexing etc for you.